# OCaml - converting trees with references to normal trees

Tags: tree, ocaml

I've got 2 types of trees:

```
type ref_tree = Node of int * ref_tree list ref
type tree = Node of int * tree list
```

I want to write a function `convert: ref_tree -> tree` which gets tree with neighbours saved as references to list containing them and outputs a tree where references are changed to normal lists. Here's what I tried:

```
let rec convert t =
        match t with
        | Node (x, l) ->
            if (!l = []) then Node (x, []) else
            Node (x, (List.map convert !l))
```

But OCaml returns an error when trying to compile it:

```
if (!l = []) then Node (x, []) else
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type tree list ref
```

Where `This expression` points at empty list inside `Node (x, [])`. Why is there a type mismatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you define two constructor `Node`, with the second definition (`type tree = Node of …`) shadowing the first one.

This means that when you're matching against `t` and destructuring it as
`Node(x, l)`, OCaml sees this as a `tree`, not a `ref_tree` (and as a consequence sees `l` as a `tree list` instead of a `ref_tree list ref`)

One way to fix this is to change the `ref_tree` constructor :

```
# type ref_tree = Ref_node of int * ref_tree list ref;;
type ref_tree = Ref_node of int * ref_tree list ref

# let rec convert t =
          match t with
          | Ref_node (x, l) ->
              if (!l = []) then Node (x, []) else
              Node (x, (List.map convert !l));;
val convert : ref_tree -> tree = <fun>
```

(another way would be to define those types in modules `Tree` and `RefTree` and using `Tree.Node` and `RefTree.Node`)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler gets confused between your two `Node` constructors (one of `ref_tree` and one of `tree`). You can help it out in various ways, including:

```
let rec convert t =
  match (t : ref_tree) with
  | Node (x, l) ->
     if (!l = []) then Node (x, []) else
       Node (x, (List.map convert !l))
```